# Deploying arrange(desc(.)) on each variable passed previously via enquos

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

## Background

Using [`rlang`](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang) I've a [simple summary function for `dplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html) that counts a number of missing observations within a variable per provided groups. *I would like to return the results in a **descending** order of grouping variables.*

## Sample data

```
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(123)
test_data <- tibble(dates = seq.Date(
    from = as.Date.character(x = "01-01-2000", format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    to = as.Date.character(x = "31-12-2010", format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
    by = "day"
)) %>%
    transmute(
        t_year = lubridate::year(dates),
        t_mnth = lubridate::month(dates),
        t_day = lubridate::day(dates),
        tst_var = if_else(rnorm(n()) > .8, NA_real_, rnorm(n()))
    )
```

## Summary function

### Working version

```
quick_smry <- function(df, x, ...) {
    group_by_vars <- enquos(...)
    check_var <- enquo(x)
    df %>% 
        group_by(!!!group_by_vars) %>% 
        summarise(num_missing = sum(is.na(!!check_var)))
}
```

### Desired results

```
test_data %>% 
    group_by(t_year, t_mnth) %>% 
    summarise(num_missing = sum(is.na(tst_var))) %>% 
    arrange(desc(t_year), desc(t_mnth))
```

### Problem

Implementing `arrange(desc(x))` call so it can handle *each* of the variables passed initially via `enquos`. I.e. if there are 5 grouping variables passed via in `enquos` this should be equivalent of `arrange(desc(var1)) .... arrange(desc(var5))`.

#### Attempt

Naturally, this doesn't work:

```
quick_smry <- function(df, x, ...) {
    group_by_vars <- enquos(...)
    check_var <- enquo(x)
    df %>% 
        group_by(!!!group_by_vars) %>% 
        summarise(num_missing = sum(is.na(!!check_var))) %>%
        # Desc call should be created for each of the group variables
        arrange(desc(!!!group_by_vars))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`arrange_at`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/arrange_all.html) like this:

```
quick_smry <- function(df, x, ...) {
    group_by_vars <- enquos(...)
    check_var <- enquo(x)
    df %>% 
        group_by(!!!group_by_vars) %>% 
        summarise(num_missing = sum(is.na(!!check_var))) %>%
        arrange_at(group_by_vars, desc)
}

quick_smry(test_data, tst_var, t_year, t_mnth)
```